# EXCEL VBA User Defined Function - why do I get the error "function not defined" while I use it in the Workbook where it is defined?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In the same Workbook, I have defined the function:

```
Public Function toto(val As Integer) As Integer
    toto = val * 2
End Function
```

Here is the editor view:

[image]

And in the Worksheet, in a cell, I use the formula:

[image]

But the result is (translation: *#NAME?*):

[image]

Also, in the VBA exec Window itself, opened from Excel, I get the following error when trying to execute:

```
toto(2)
```

[image]

Translation : *Compilation error: Sub or Function not defined*

What do I miss?

Comment: Where did you put the code? It need to be in a public module.

Comment: FWIW the `Val` parameter is shadowing the `VBA.Conversion.Val` function and should probably be renamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on what @Jo.lass and @vincent-g said, you need to have your code in a module, not in worksheet or workbook code. See here:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just putting it in a module by itself? Also have you called the module the same thing? The other instance where you can get the #NAME error is when there is a name conflict.

Comment: @lalebarde no, that's not what you have. Per your screenshot, your code is in the code-behind of `Feuil5`, not in a standard module.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the left part "Module 1". Now it works !

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing the function in a worksheet in VBE, try writing it in a new module.
Works for me at least.